# Instance status is OutOfService in Load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created a load balancer in amazon AWS.I created the load balancer in order to set up an ssl in server which already had another domain with SSL.The load balancer was working fine till today.But sometime before I noticed that the status of the instance has changed to Outofservice.

[image]

Im new to aws and couldnt find what is going wrong.

My health check is set as

[image]

Please help out.

Comment: At the moment it will take 20 minutes for your instance to be considered healthy. The ping interval should be something like 10-15 seconds instead of 120.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my checklist to troubleshoot this type of issue

- Is the Security group of your instance OK ?  ELB needs to have access to your instance for the health check
- Is your Web / App server correctly running on the instance ?  Does it accept connection requests ?
- Is the HTTP return code of your health check URL 200 ?  If your healthcheck URL returns anything else (a 30x redirect for example), ELB will consider your instance invalid.  You can check this with curl -I  on Linux instances.

HTH

--Seb

Comment: Im getting  HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable: Back-end server is at capacity
Connection: keep-alive when I tried Your curl -I..What can be the issue?

Comment: Just to be sure did you use the instance URL? Not the ELB URL, right ? curl -I must be executed against the instance (or from the instance itself if Security Group does not authorise access to it).  Typically : ssh to the instance, then type 'curl -I http://localhost'