# Adding load balancer to AWS EB EC2 - 503 Service Unavailable: Back-end server is at capacity

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2

I have an AWS Elasticbeanstalk instance for a PHP API which I need to add SSL to for https.

To set it up with https, I am using Cloudfront to serve the EB app, `http://myappdomainname.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/`,  through `*.myappdomainname.com`. In this case it'd be `api.myappdomainname.com`. And I'm creating a load balancer to attach to the EB app, to which I can attach the SSL cert.

After setting up

- cloudfront,

  [image]
- Route 53 CName,

  [image]
- and the classic load balancer,

If I try to access `https://api.myappdomainname.com` I get this as a response:

> Error: 503 Service Unavailable: Back-end server is at capacity

This seems to be because the load balancer is out of service:

[image]

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22663743/instance-status-is-outofservice-in-load-balancer) recommended to check these three things:

**Is the Security group of your instance OK ? ELB needs to have access to your instance for the health check**

- Not 100% sure what this means, but my load balancer is attached to this security group which allows for connections that I need. The Security instance seems Okay:

  [image]

**Is your Web / App server correctly running on the instance ? Does it accept connection requests ?**

- Yes, it seems like it's correctly running on the instance:

  [image]

**Is the HTTP return code of your health check URL 200 ? If your healthcheck URL returns anything else (a 30x redirect for example), ELB will consider your instance invalid. You can check this with curl -I on Linux instances.**

- Not sure what this means. How can I check my Healthcheck URL?

Are there any other things I should check to figure out why it remains as OutOfService?

Comment: Regarding security groups, check the security group attached to Beanstalk Instance, verifying it allows inbound from ELB. From the image you shared it seems like the security group attached to the ELB seems alright. For the health check, verity whether the health check path doesn't have any redirects (For example if you point to a root page which will redirect to login upon visiting the site) health check will fail

Comment: @Ashan It doesn't seem to be throwing that error now, but my https route, https://api.dynamicdentaledu.com/, won't load (no errors either). As you can see from above, I have the cert attached to my load balancer, route 53 pointing to the `*.mydomainname.com`, and cloudfront set up

Comment: Are you pointing to the https url from cloudfront? if so, make sure you whitelist the headers and not forward the HOST header.